# Perl Inline::java module

Tags: java, perl

I am trying to install Inline::Java module in cpan but getting the following error. Please can someone help. Thank you.

```
Welcome to the Inline::Java installation procedure.

A Java 2 SDK is required to install and use Inline::Java. Please 
specify your Java 2 SDK installation directory using the J2SDK 
option to Makefile.PL as such:

perl Makefile.PL J2SDK=/path/to/your/j2sdk/installation

You can set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to specify your
Java 2 SDK installation directory. For example, if you are using
the CPAN installer you can do:

JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/j2sdk/installation cpan Inline::Java
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
 PATL/Inline-Java-0.53.tar.gz
 /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
 Running make test
 Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
Make had some problems, won't install
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
Failed during this command:
PATL/Inline-Java-0.53.tar.gz                 : writemakefile NO '/usr/bin/perl     Makefile.PL' returned status 256
```

I haven't used java anytime. Please throw some light on it for proper understanding for java. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What operating system are you on? Also, what are your intentions with Inline-Java if you haven't used java anytime?

Comment: Google for "JAva 2 SDK" and download from www.oracle.com/...

Comment: It is centos os 64 bit. I am trying to run a java code via perl wrapper Inline::Java

Answer (score 0):

This helped me out

```
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-linux-6-install-java-sdk/
```

And I am able to run the sample java code. Thanks.